# Jmeter:- Thread group executes twice on Unix

Tags: java, unix, jmeter, beanshell

I've a test plan in jmeter which m executing only for single user as shows in the image below:-
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCHjt.jpg]

But in View result tree each samplers has two entries, not able to identify this issue. Any help on this would me much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I37ZJ.jpg]

Note:- This is happening only on Unix, on Windows it works fine.

Comment: I think having "Start next thread loop" checked after an error is unusual.  I always use "Continue".

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I had in "HTTP Request Defaults" a basepath "Path" that was common for all request, and then a subpath in every "HTTP Request".

I expected request URL to be `http://host:port/basepath/subpath`, but I got `http://host:port/basepath`, so it redirected to another page, and therefore there were two HTTP requests.

Setting the complete `basepath/subpath` in every "HTTP Request" and leaving path empty in "HTTP Request Defaults" did work for me.